# force last element of justify-content-around to be align with the first element of the previous line

Tags: bootstrap-4

I use bootstrap4 and I wrote the following code

```
<div class="row justify-content-around">
<div class="col-md-5">
    first
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
    second
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
    third
</div>
```

third element is centered on the second line but I want it to be vertical aligned with the first element (first of the first line). Is it possible please ?

Comment: Just as information, my only solution for this is to add a fourth div with class="invisible". But maybe I can do better ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood properly but I guess you want "first" and "second" horizontally aligned in the first row and "third" vertically aligned with "first" on the second row?

If this is the case why don't you use 2 rows instead of just 1

```
<div class='row'>
 <div class='col-12 col-md-6>first</div>
 <div class='col-12 col-md-6>second</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
 <div class='col-12 col-md-6>third</div>
</div>
```

Comment: because I do not want col-6 size but col-5 and use justify-content-around. If I put justify-content-around on each rows and if the last one have only one element it will be centered. And I do not know the amount of item I have to display

Comment: Try to add also the class d-flex to the row then or place a div after the div of the row with these 2 classes "d-flex justify-content-around".